# Buzzing noise after reassembling iMac 20" 2009

Tags: imac, hardware

I changed my iMac's hard drive to a SSD, following the iFix It guide. It all worked well, but after some hours using the machine, a buzzing noise appeared in the top left corner of it.

I read in the forums people having problems with defective PSU, but mine was working fine before disassembling the iMac. What do you think I could've made wrong in the assembling?

Thanks

-- edit --

curiously, after keeping the computer some minutes unplugged, and turning it on again, the sounds disappears. It's actually working for a few hours and the noise didn't come back yet. Weird.

Comment: Which iFixit guide?..

Comment: In step 17 of the tear down of a 
iMac Intel 20" EMC 2266
Model A1224 / Early 2009 / 2.66 GHz Core 2 Duo processor.. It looks like the PSU is situated there. I would check to make sure the connectors are firmly in. 

https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iMac+Intel+20-Inch+EMC+2266+Teardown/658

Comment: Did you check the PSU connections

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause would be the fan causing the noise. See this post from bMike 'Is it possible to install an SSD ...imac'  where he points out that 
"..the immediate downsides - You will need special tools and be handling some delicate parts. Also, there is concern that the temperature sensing since the 2009 model iMac causes the fans to run faster with non-apple drives."  I have also had the problem with the fan going into overdrive and creating a horrible buzzing, so I am aware they are susceptible to this happening.  It is also possible that some foreign material got lodged around the fan, so that is worth checking too, and definitely keep an eye on the temperature.

Comment: From experience of a fan buzzing in MacBook Pro it is because the fan is faulty not that it is working harder. Replacing a fan can fix this. But initially i would say fan is the issue here but I cannot suggest this the because I do not know its location in this device. And are you confirming it is the top right hand corner by posting this as an answer rather than a comment? Even if you do, your post is maybe more helpful as a comment.

Comment: I don't think it's a fan related issue. Because when I turn off the mac, the noise continues, only a little weaker. The sound is more like an eletric buzz then a fan noise. It only stopped when I took it off the energy plug.

Comment: new info: curiously, after keeping the computer some minutes unplugged, and turning it on again, the sounds disappears. It's actually working for a few hours and the noise didn't come back yet. Weird.